# What is the correct placement of actions buttons

Tags: buttons, layout, edit

I am working on an application where user's data will be frequently added and updated.

In sample 1, I have added 'add address' links in each row per category for quick addition but it is breaking the visual of the page and it is repetitive. Also, it will not support bulk operation and creating confusion(I have tested it with 3 users).

Sample 2 is clear and caters single and bulk operation but user has to select the record before he adds the address.

Question:

1. What do you think? which one is the better solution?
2. How to arrange the 'edit' link?
3. Do you know any application with the same scenario?

**Sample 1** [image]

**Sample 2:**[image]

Comment: Just adding on what @ferreldoc mentioned
Can we add one more column that displays an edit icon on each row
clicking on opens a where user can edit all three addresses

Answer (score 1):

You could have a single Edit icon or link near each candidate's name that would allow your users to edit all three addresses for that candidate. It would reduce the clutter of the first option and provide bulk editing at the individual candidate level.

You could also have a Bulk Edit button that opens another view to allow bulk editing of all addresses for all candidates.

Answer (score 0):

based on the assumption that **frequent** addition and editing of user data is required on this application, I would personally go for sample 1.

Instead of using edit links you can consider putting visual placeholders (the kind like empty rounded rectangles) within the rows where users can edit information to update their addresses, and automatic addition of rows to prompt users to enter more information directly into the table.

You may like to take some ideas/ design elements off Microsoft Excel and Google Sheets. They have established standards in user data entry and correction.

Adding a picture below to illustrate what I wrote above. Hope you don't mind me editing off your sample picture.

[image: picture to illustrate the idea I described]

Answer (score 0):

You should go with **Sample 1**, if you are not having any mass selection and action like Delete All, Enable/Disable All you can even remove the checkbox at start from **Sample 1**.

You can do some improvement in the design such as:

1. Remove the Click to add and edit action links.
2. Add empty textboxes with watermarks such as "Residential Address" etc.
3. Use double click and focus out options. When the user double clicks make the text fields editable and on focus out save the data and make the field noneditable again.

In your **Sample 2**, you are increasing the user journey every time user needs to select the checkbox first, than click on the button (Add Residential etc.).
For adding 1 user record the user had to click three buttons and in 3 different textboxes and after all this the user need to save the data by may be clicking on save button.

So your **Sample 1** is the go option. You can consider the extra features suggested above if you want.